# SQL Server 2012 - Issue Enabling CDC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

I am trying to enable CDC on my database using windows authentication user with "SYSADMIN" privileges, but sql server (2012) is giving the following error (See attached snapshot of the error for further details).

```
"Could not update metadata that indicates database %s is enabled for change data capture.
The failure occurred when executing the command 'sp_addrolemember' 'db_owner' 'cdc'. 
The error returned was 1205: "
```

I am executing the script in following sequence.

1. Disable cdc script using "EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_DB"
2. Enable cdc script

Can anyone please help me in identifying the cause for this issue?

[Enable CDC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISUU.png)

Comment: Error 1205 is "transaction was deadlocked" (if the error number is a SQL server error, which the message isn't clear about). Try putting the database in single-user mode before executing the statements (`USE mydb; ALTER DATABASE mydb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`) to see if that helps getting exclusive access. I hope you have a backup to restore in case CDC is in half-usable state from which it can't recover.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: The error number is of SQL server. Can you please explain the half-usable state of CDC? Is there any way to determine or identify if the CDC is in that state?

Comment: I meant: try running the statements in single user mode. If you don't get error 1205, but some other error indicating CDC can't be activated, this may be a result of the partial failure you had earlier, and you may need to restore from backup to proceed further. This is a hypothetical concern; try getting it to work in single user mode first.